Simulated Execution of Redirections
My shell is the Korn Shell, but I think the problem (and its eventual remedy) applies to other shells as well.
I usually build a "simulation mode" into my scripts to test potentially destructive/state-changing commands up front. Like this:
# export SIMULATE='print -'
[...]
$SIMULATE /path/to/hazardous_command

When the first line is uncommented the command is not executed but only printed instead.
The problem I have is: if the command in question involves some redirection this won't work:
$SIMULATE /path/to/hazardous_command > /path/to/file 2>/path/to/other_file

Is there any elegant(!) solution I haven't been thinking of as now? I know I could do:
if [ -n "$SIMULATE" ] ; then
    $SIMULATE "/path/to/hazardous_command > /path/to/file 2>/path/to/other_file"
else
    /path/to/hazardous_command > /path/to/file 2>/path/to/other_file
fi

but this is not really making the code clearer and I would prefer a "plug-in" solution of some sorts, although up to now I came up short.
I have also thought about (uncomment either of the export-statements):
# export SIMULATE='eval '
# export SIMULATE='print -'
[...]
$SIMULATE "/path/to/hazardous_command >/path/to/file 2>/path/to/other_file"

this would work but this replaces the problem of the redirections with the problem of the quotes: what if the command in question involves quoted strings? Escaping the quotes would work, but ultimately I would still have to maintain two different versions of the command (one to be printed, one to be executed).
So, has anybody an idea how to overcome this?

Basically, you need to tell the shell to not evaluate the code.
You could do something like
alias start_simulate= end_simulate=
# alias start_simulate='cat<<"end_simulate"'

start_simulate
/path/to/hazardous_command >/path/to/file 2>/path/to/other_file
end_simulate

Note that nothing must follow start_simulate and the end_simulate must be on its own and at the start of the line.
Or:
if simulating; then
  alias 'simulate_eval=print -r --'
else
  alias simulate_eval=eval
fi
simulate_eval '/path/to/hazardous_command >/path/to/file 2>/path/to/other_file'

Your $SIMULATE has a few issues:

print by default expands \ escape sequences, you need -r to avoid it.
export is to make sure the variable is passed in the environment of commands that are executed, it makes little sense here, unless you're executing other ksh commands that are going to interpret code that use $SIMULATE.
the $SIMULATE when unquoted in list context is subject to split+glob so its behaviour is subject to the current value of $IFS. For a variable to hold more than more element, you use an array (set with set -A simulate print -r -- in ksh88, also simulte=(print -r --) in ksh93 a la zsh, and then used as "${simulate[@]}" (note the quotes which are important to prevent split+glob). Here a function or alias would make more sense than a variable.


So, basically you suggest to turn the command into a here-document? This is a great idea, I haven't thought about that. Regarding the "exports": I actually use a slightly more complicated version but tried to strip that down for the sake of clarity. You are right, I could have used a typeset as it is written here.

I solved this problem like so:
Instead of using $SIMULATE; print the commands to be executed and review them and then redirect the output to a shell for execution.
So,

change this,
if [ -n "$SIMULATE" ] ; then
    $SIMULATE "/path/to/hazardous_command > /path/to/file 2>/path/to/other_file"
else
    /path/to/hazardous_command > /path/to/file 2>/path/to/other_file
fi


to this
## print commands before running them
#
function doSimulate() {
  echo  '/path/to/hazardous_command > /path/to/file 2>/path/to/other_file'
}

##  run commands
#
function dontSimulate() {
  doSimulate  |  /bin/sh
}


Then,
./doSimulate prints
/path/to/hazardous_command > /path/to/file 2>/path/to/other_file

and,
./doSimulate  |  /bin/sh just runs hazardous

though
./dontSimulate does the same thing.




Though, having tried a similar approach, the dollar sign $DEBUG design pattern, I recommend printing and reviewing the commands before piping them to a shell because it allows you to easily check special characters, escapes, etc. before turning them loose on the file system.

Note that the > /dev/stdout in  echo something > /dev/stdout is wrong on Linux/Cygwin systems and pointless on other systems.

ITYM function cmd { or cmd() { rather than cmd {.
